# Event error 9009 on IIS after create new project with .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, iis-10, asp.net-core-2.1

I working with .NET Core 2.0 application few months. Today I started creating .NET Core 2.1 application. On Visual studio everything working fine. The database, logging, services, file saving, everything. But after publish and deploy it on IIS server I get this error:

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure
```

After open event viewer I found this tree errors:

```
The Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to delete the history directory 'C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000100'.  The directory will be skipped and ignored.  Note that the directory may still get deleted in the future if the service restarts.  The data field contains the error number.
The Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to delete the history directory 'C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000101\schema'.  The directory will be skipped and ignored.  Note that the directory may still get deleted in the future if the service restarts.  The data field contains the error number.
The Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to delete the history directory 'C:\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000101'.  The directory will be skipped and ignored.  Note that the directory may still get deleted in the future if the service restarts.  The data field contains the error number.
```

I looking for those directories and they do not exist.
For resolve this problem I tried these steps:

- I restarted the IIS server.
- I restarted Application host helper service.
- I installed Runtime & Hosting Bundle 2.1.2.

But still the same problem. For first I trying resolve this problem on my IIS server on my PC because I have webhosting and there also not working. I can't change permission. In my PC ofc, yes but not at webhosting server of the provider.

I have installed these nuget packages:

- HtmlAgilityPack v1.8.5
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App v2.1.1
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v.2.1.1
- Microsoft.NetCore.App v2.1.0
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design v2.1.1
- Serilog.AspNetCore v2.1.1
- Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile v.3.1.0

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Hosting Bundle https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Then check on your IIS that you have the registered Module AspNetCoreModule

Comment: I tried this as you can see in my post. I wroted: I installed Runtime & Hosting Bundle 2.1.2. I check that and i have installed Microsoft .NET Core 2.1.2 - Windows Server Hosting (x86)

Comment: IIS -> Select your server name menu -> Modules

Comment: Also your publish should create a Web.config file with the following content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\myApp.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: You also need to know if your app is self-contained or Framework dependant

Comment: My app is Framework dependant. And only one i gues irrelevant different in my generated web.config: path="*" verb="*" with * between of "".

Comment: Check if your app is on the right level on IIS, maybe test copying other app that works in its place

Comment: To isolate the problem , take the template app similar to your own app that comes with Visual studio and make it run on IIS. Then you can diagnose if is the ASP.NET core Module the problem or something within your app that creates the problem. Just deploy the default app template

Comment: Missing that bundle yields 500.19. Don't mislead others.